# Python script to match date in particular time interval

Tags: python

We have access logs which contain logging in below format:

```
0.93 172.19.180.93 - - - [14/Mar/2016:11:07:22 +0130] "GET /MyWeb/appResources/css/ng-tags-input.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1077 **0/4864**
```

Now, want to parse each line using python script to identify number of such acess request occured between 10.00 to 19:00 hr on particular date.
Trying Something like:

```
for fname in filenames_245:
    with open(fname) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if re.search('[0-9][0-9]//Mar//2016/:[1]',line):
                outfile.write(line)
```

Can someone please suggest the correct usage of pattern to get required data.

Comment: So are you matching only those dates from 01/Mar/2016 to 31/Mar/2016?

Comment: Yes, we have one access file per day. So we will parse 31 files to get total no of hits to the application in Month of March.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression can work, but the problem is that you're using two slashes instead of one. So you should write it as `'[0-9][0-9]/Mar/2016:[1]'`.

Note that to escape a character you should prepend it with a backslash (\) not a forward slash (/). But here you don't need to escape anything.

Answer (score 0):

re.search() evaluates to true even if there is no match, because ir return's an SRE object, and you regex was wrong on the [1], you want:

You want:

```
re.findall('\d\d/Mar/2016:1', data)
```

Comment: What if the date was in invalid format like `55/InvalidMonth/3500:18:00` ... ?

Comment: This answer only addresses the question of finding a specific known pattern. For proper date matching and handling a more complex regex would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> re.search("14/Mar/2016:1", line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f37cd4179f0>
```

or

```
>>> re.search("{0}/{1}/{2}:1".format(date, month, year), line)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f37cd417ac0>
```

if you want to pass your days as variables.

Regarding Joao Pinto, search returns none if there is no match:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html